# XML Parser in SQL Server 2012; Not returning any rows when child elements are not present

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following XML message, from which the data needs to be inserted into a table.

The XML parser works when I've all elements in the msg like below:

```
DECLARE @XmlVal XML=
'
<Customers>
<CustomerID> C001 </CustomerID>
<CustomerName> Carlos </CustomerName>
    <Orders>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>100</OrderID> 
            <OrderDetail>
                <ProductID>10</ProductID>
                <Quantity>5 </Quantity>
            </OrderDetail >
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>101</OrderID> 
            <OrderDetail>
                <ProductID>10</ProductID>
                <Quantity>5 </Quantity>
            </OrderDetail >
        </Order>
    </Orders>
<Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>    
</Customers>
'
```

This works well and returns 2 rows with the help of following query.

```
  SELECT 
    Cust.value('CustomerID[1]','varchar(100)') AS CustomerID,
    Cust.value('CustomerName[1]','varchar(100)') AS CustomerName,
    Cust.value('Address[1]','varchar(100)') AS Address,
    Orders.value('../OrderID[1]','varchar(10)') AS OrderID,
    Orders.value('ProductID[1]','varchar(80)') AS ProductID,
    Orders.value('Quantity[1]','varchar(3)') AS Quantity
 FROM @XmlVal.nodes('//Customers') AS i(Cust)
    CROSS APPLY @XmlVal.nodes('//Customers/Orders/Order/OrderDetail') AS j(Orders)
```

But when I use the xml message like below I get only one row. I need the second row too with CustomerID, CustomerName, Address, OrderID with ProductID and Quantity empty.

```
<Customers>
<CustomerID> C001 </CustomerID>
<CustomerName> Carlos </CustomerName>
    <Orders>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>100</OrderID> 
            <OrderDetail>
                <ProductID>10</ProductID>
                <Quantity>5 </Quantity>
            </OrderDetail >
        </Order>
        <Order>
            <OrderID>101</OrderID>              
        </Order>
    </Orders>
<Address> Address line 1, 2, 3</Address>    
</Customers>
```

Is it possible ? Is my approach wrong ?

I can not change the xml format. Is there any way I could change the SQL query to get the second row ?

Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Yes - of course - only **one** of your `<Order>` nodes has a subnode `<OrderDetail>` which you use in your XPath - therefore, **only one row** is returned .... if you want the second `<Order>`, too, then you need to have **at least** an empty `<OrderDetail />` tag inside that node

Comment: I can not change the xml format. Is there any way I could change the SQL query to get the second row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query a bit:

- break the call to `.nodes()` into three parts - the first for the `<Customers>` node (as you have it now), the second one for the `<Order>` subnodes (based on the customer node) and the third for the `<OrderDetail>` (if present)
- since the third level of nodes is optional, you need to use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY`
- and I would also recommend to use **more appropriate** datatypes in your query - all those elements that are **numeric** should be converted as such - into an `INT` or so - don't just use `varchar` everywhere out of lazyness

So try this statement:

```
SELECT 
    Cust.value('(CustomerID)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS CustomerID,
    Cust.value('(CustomerName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS CustomerName,
    Cust.value('(Address)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Address,
    Orders.value('(OrderID)[1]', 'int') AS OrderID,
    OrderDetails.value('(ProductID)[1]','int') AS ProductID,
    OrderDetails.value('(Quantity)[1]', 'int') AS Quantity
FROM 
    -- first level - get the <Customers> nodes
    @XmlVal.nodes('Customers') AS i(Cust)
CROSS APPLY 
    -- second level - get the <Orders>/<Order> sub-nodes under <Customer>
    Cust.nodes('Orders/Order') AS j(Orders)
OUTER APPLY 
    -- third, optional level - get the <OrderDetail> sub-nodes under <Order> - if present
    Orders.nodes('OrderDetail') AS k(OrderDetails)
```